# custom payment gateway response leads to white page

Tags: magento-1.8, php, javascript, payment-gateway

i'm creating my own payment method and gateway but the payment controller doesn't seem to handle the response of the gateway properly.

the gateway sends one POST-var as response with a html form submitted by javascript to /magento/mygateway/payment/response but then it doesn't lead back to the shop. instead it shows just a white page.
i also tried responding to /magento/index.php/mygateway/payment/response but that just leads to the homepage of the store. both methods place the order successfully but when i view the orders in admin panel it says that they were not paid.

here's the code of the `responseAction()` function that should be triggered by the response:

```
public function responseAction() {
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {


        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        if ($data['valid'] == $order->getId()) $validated = true;

        $orderId = '123'; // Generally sent by gateway

        if($validated) {
            // Payment was successful, so update the order's state, send order email and move to the success page
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
            $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true, 'Gateway has authorized the payment.');

            $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
            $order->setEmailSent(true);

            $order->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsQuoteId();

            Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
        }
        else {
            // There is a problem in the response we got
            $this->cancelAction();
            Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/failure', array('_secure'=>true));
        }
    }
    else
        Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('');
}
```

and here's the code of the gateway (it doesn't make any sense, it's only for testing):

```
<?php
$orderid = $_POST['orderid'];
?>
<form name="mygatewayform" method="post" action="http://kgwshop.intothis.org/magento/mygateway/payment/response">
    <input type="hidden" name="valid" value="<?=$orderid?>">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.mygatewayform.submit();
</script>
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Myname_Mygateway>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Myname_Mygateway>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <mygateway>
        <class>Myname_Mygateway_Model</class>
      </mygateway>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <mygateway>
        <class>Myname_Mygateway_Helper</class>
      </mygateway>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <mygateway>
        <class>Myname_Mygateway_Block</class>
      </mygateway>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <default>
    <payment>
      <mygateway>
        <model>mygateway/standard</model>
        <active>1</active>
        <order_status>pending</order_status>
        <title>My Gateway</title>
        <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
        <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
      </mygateway>
    </payment>
  </default>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <mygateway>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Myname_Mygateway</module>
          <frontName>mygateway</frontName>
        </args>
      </mygateway>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

whole PaymentController.php:

```
<?php


class Myname_Mygateway_PaymentController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    // The redirect action is triggered when someone places an order
    public function redirectAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','mygateway',array('template' => 'mygateway/redirect.phtml'));
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    // The response action is triggered when your gateway sends back a response after processing the customer's payment
    public function responseAction() {
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

            if ($data['valid'] == $order->getId()) $validated = true;

            $orderId = '123'; // Generally sent by gateway

            if($validated) {
                // Payment was successful, so update the order's state, send order email and move to the success page
                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
                $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
                $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true, 'Gateway has authorized the payment.');

                $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                $order->setEmailSent(true);

                $order->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsQuoteId();

                Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
            }
            else {
                // There is a problem in the response we got
                $this->cancelAction();
                Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/failure', array('_secure'=>true));
            }
        }
        else
            Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('');
    }

    // The cancel action is triggered when an order is to be cancelled
    public function cancelAction() {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
            if($order->getId()) {
                // Flag the order as 'cancelled' and save it
                $order->cancel()->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, 'Gateway has declined the payment.')->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.htaccess in the same folder as PaymentController.php:

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Comment: Hi, can you also post your config.xml code, as your module configuration, especially the router configuration will be essential in answering this question

Comment: @ProxiBlue i edited the question

Comment: Ok, according to your config.xml routers configuration, your URL of /magento/mygateway/payment/response is correct, if you site runs under the subfolder /magento/ and your controller is named Payment.php and the action response is defined. Can you confirm you have the controller located here: /controllers/Payment.php. Can you add the controllers class definition as well please. Have you confirmed that the action is in fact executed, by placing a simple die('i am here'); as the first code in the action. Your issue could be an exception inside the routine itself. Use a debugger

Comment: Are you using a debugger? (xdebug?)

Comment: @ProxiBlue my controller is named PaymentController.php, so i changed the url to /magento/mygateway/PaymentController/response but now magento throws an error 404. and i'm not using a debugger

Comment: i tried adding die('i am here'); in responseaction but that only leads me to the homepage of the shop when i use /magento/mygateway/payment/response

Comment: i think /magento/mygateway/payment/response is correct because /magento/mygateway/payment/redirect is working

Comment: now the die('i am here'); is working (i forgot to upload the .htaccess), but when i remove it i still get just a whit page.

Comment: moving around the `die('i am here');` i found out, that it's working till the line `$order->sendNewOrderEmail();`

Comment: i deleted `$order->sendNewOrderEmail(); $order->setEmailSent(true);` but now it crashes at `$order->save();`

Comment: Apologies, that should have been /controllers/PaymentController.php

Comment: The reasons can be multitude. You need to use a debugger, and an IDE that supports debug breakpoints. This is what a debugger is meant for (hence the name ;) ) You can identify the issue, and solve these kind of issues quite easy. Some basic debug steps identified the issue quote clearly as not being that your controller action is reached, but that the code in the action has issues. Hope you manage t track this down.

Comment: looking at your controller code. you are using the $order object before it was instantiated, in this line if `($data['valid'] == $order->getId()) $validated = true;`

Comment: Please update question with debugging info.